# Tmux + Vim: Won't copy to clipboard

Tags: vim, tmux

I am using the latest version of Tmux (2+), macOS High Sierra, and the latest version of VIM.

I have this line in my tmux.conf config, which used to work:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy'
```

I've tried adding this:

```
bind-key -T edit-mode-vi Up send-keys -X history-up
bind-key -T edit-mode-vi Down send-keys -X history-down
unbind-key -T copy-mode-vi Space     ;   bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
unbind-key -T copy-mode-vi Enter     ;   bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-pipe-and-cancel "reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
unbind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-v       ;   bind-key -T copy-mode-vi C-v send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
unbind-key -T copy-mode-vi [         ;   bind-key -T copy-mode-vi [ send-keys -X begin-selection
unbind-key -T copy-mode-vi ]         ;   bind-key -T copy-mode-vi ] send-keys -X copy-selection
```

and then this:

```
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi 'v' send -X begin-selection
bind-key -Tcopy-mode-vi 'y' send -X copy-selection
```

Neither work for me when I go to vim and either copy with `y` or `"*y`.

I've looked every where and tried every solution, restarted my tmux config , and even opened a new tmux window after every change (with `tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf`), but nothing has worked.

I do not want to install Macvim.

Here's a link to my dotfiles (tmux.conf and vimrc are in the root):
https://github.com/PotatoLabs/dotfiles

Comment: Does your vim build have clipboard support built in?

Comment: Hi Christian. Here's a link to my dotfiles: https://github.com/PotatoLabs/dotfiles

Comment: I think he was asking if your vim binary itself has +clipboard support built in, not whether you've enabled it in your vimrc.

Comment: Ooo My fault, how would I be able to check that?

Comment: run it with `vim --version`

Comment: I see `-clipboard`. Do you know how I would turn it on?

Comment: You'd have to either compile it from source with clipboard support, or install another version (such as gvim, maybe?) that has it compiled in.

Comment: got it. thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to the comments I figured it out!

When you run `vim --version`:

```
➜  dotfiles git:(master) ✗ vim --version | grep clipboard
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +virtualedit
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xterm_clipboard
```

Make sure it's `+clipboard`, not `-clipboard`. Mac unfortunately comes with vim compiled with `-clipboard`. Run `brew install vim`, and then add `alias vim="/usr/local/bin/vim"` to your aliases.